# How do I get the source HTML for the initial page load (before stuff get lazy loaded in)?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

In chrome, if I do "View Source" after the page is fully loaded, the HTML contains a bunch of styles and stuff that are lazy loaded in after initial page load.

Comment: Turn off Javascript before loading the page?

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. If you actually select "View Source", triggering navigation to a `view-source:` URL, it should show you the exact code sent from the server. If you open the Web Inspector, *that* shows you the current state of the DOM, including changes.

Comment: I believe @JeremyBanks is spot on, "view source" in any browser does ***not*** show content loaded with javascript, but the original unmodified source, so this is not an issue.